# How can I get FFmpeg to better use GPU and CPU resources the way HandBrake does?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, cpu, gpu, video-conversion

Occasionally I needed interpolation feature for my videos, but i failed to find option in HandBrake GUI (if HandBrake already have it, please let me know). After some trying to launch minterpolate from latest FFMpeg, it is very surprising for me about very old FFMpeg "feat" from more than ten years ago - it is still cant use GPU nor CPU properly from the box (seriously, 0-5% gpu 33% cpu?).

Commands like `-threads` doesn't”t works (like 10 years ago, maybe it just for demonstration purposes?). While HandBrake using GPU and CPU properly without any flaws and code 10 bit hevc fhd long-hour videos in minutes.

Am I not aware about certain commands(commands like `-hwaccel qsv hevc_qsv` from manual only producing errors, after some research I found `output_format_qsv`, that works but still not have HandBrake normal speed), or it is just FFMPEG been that bad from the very beginning?

P.S. Intel 11-135g7 SoC, latest drivers installed (but looks like it isn’t a problem, because other utilities work fine), Windows 10
my latest command that works:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel_output_format qsv -i input.mkv -pix_fmt p010le -c:v hevc_qsv -load_plugin hevc_hw -b:v 25M -threads 8 -vf "minterpolate=fps=60:mi_mode=mci:mc_mode=aobmc:me_mode=bidir:vsbmc=1" -preset veryslow output.mkv
```

Comment: It's not ffmpeg - it's the codec that does it.

Comment: No. Even 264 with other video without minterpolate cant achieve normal speed. Any command from ffmpeg get the same cpu gpu consumption. It IS definitely ffmpeg trait from decades ago. Or i doing smth wrong.(point me)

Comment: What are your computer & GPU models? And especially what is your CPU.

Comment: Isn't 11-135g7 Intel SoC(it is system on a chip for mobile device, not classic computer component) have only one configuration? I think it is been clear from the main post.

Comment: Your post is nothing but clear... Your CPU is not a "SOC", it's a classical Core i5 CPU, with an integrated Iris GPU. The QSV codec runs on the GPU, and afaik the `minterpolate` filter runs on the CPU and uses only one core (regardless the `nthread` you set). `minterpolate` is quite slow, so in your command it's very likely the bottleneck.

Comment: For a more useful discussion, please report the encode times you are obtaining with different ffmpeg commands (with and without minterpolate for instance), and also with Handbrake. But you have to describe the Handbrake settings, because the encode times can vary a lot depending on the settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Looks like it is really certain minterpolate problem, and it only works on CPU without any multithreading or hwaccel, like all advanced features of ffmpeg from the box.

Comment: If you can't use a different, multi-threaded filter, or a different application, you could break the file into multiple parts (do so at keyframes and output .mkv files to avoid another encoding step), run the process on multiple pieces in parallel, and then recombine the results using the concat filter. `ffmpeg -i "concat:input1|input2" -codec copy output`

Comment: @Amorphous properly interpolating the frames at the segment boudaries will be a mess.